# extracting content of an sms in android app

Tags: android

i am coding an app in which on receive of sms the content of the sms should be extracted and split the string into two parts and in separate variable. here is what i have tried. but the code doesn't work even though there are no errors.

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();


    try {

        if (bundle != null) {

            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");


            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                toast.show();
              // String[] arr=message.split(",");
                StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(message, ",");
                Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(context, "tokenizer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast1.show();
                int numberOfTokens = tokenizer.countTokens();
                String[] splitArr = new String[numberOfTokens];

                    splitArr[0] = tokenizer.nextToken();
                    splitArr[1] = tokenizer.nextToken();
                    Toast toast3 = Toast.makeText(context, splitArr[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast3.show();
                    Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(context, "split", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast2.show();
                String lat=splitArr[0];
                String lng=splitArr[1];
                Double lat1=Double.valueOf(lat);
                Double lng1=Double.valueOf(lng);
```

}}
}

Comment: It's maybe a bit too much to ask us go through your code for you. A suggestion is that you log much more, to see where it all stops. Come back with more info then.

Comment: i am not able to figure out how to read the sms received and split the content in the sms. the other logic part of the app works except for the sms. thank you

Comment: Please, tell us more. Like do you get anything in currentMessage? Does your String message contain anything? We can't/won't run your code for you! So what you do is you define the problem more clearly and then people will help you.